# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position X: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, windows, pip

When I'm trying to install [StringGenerator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/StringGenerator/0.3.0) with pip, I am prompted with this error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator> pip install StringGenerator

Collecting StringGenerator 
Using cached StringGenerator-0.3.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-build-mdvrj2cf\StringGenerator\setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    long_description = file.read()
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1264: character maps to <undefined>

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-build-mdvrj2cf\StringGenerator\
```

Comment: Try an administrator command prompt

Comment: Still getting an error.

Comment: have you tried using pip? `pip install StringGenerator`....https://pypi.python.org/pypi/StringGenerator/0.3.0

Comment: Yep, that's whats giving me the error :/

Comment: Is that really the full output from `pip`?

Comment: Also, is there really a space between `ADMINI~1` and `\AppData` in those errors? If so, that seems like a serious problem that could break all kinds of things, but I can't imagine how it could even happen.

Comment: I have installed other modules with pip no problem. Not sure why this is popping up. This is also a fresh server that I just deployed.

Comment: You need to post the full traceback of the pip install error (with the inclusion of the command you ran that produces this error). The current error message is not enough to do any debugging.

Comment: The fact that you've used `pip` before doesn't answer the question of whether that's really the full output, and whether it's the accurate output.

Comment: I have updated the post.

Answer (score 38):

The problem is caused during the setup process when reading `README.txt`. In Windows, the default encoding is cp1252, but that readme file is most likely encoded in UTF8.

The error message tells you that cp1252 codec is unable to decode the character with the byte 0x9D. When I browsed through the readme file, I found this character: `”` (also known as: "RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK"), which has the bytes 0xE2 0x80 **0x9D**, which includes the problematic byte.

What you can do is:

1. Download the package [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/StringGenerator/0.3.0)
2. Decompress the package
3. Open setup.py
4. Change the following:

From:

```
with open('README.txt') as file:
    long_description = file.read()
```

Change into:

```
with open('README.txt', encoding="utf8") as file:
    long_description = file.read()
```

This will open the file with the proper encoding.

Or you can remove these two line altogether and also remove `long_description=long_description,` at line 18 inside `setup()`.

5. In console, run `python setup.py install`
6. And you're done!

---

Since there's no actual setup in the setup.py script, you can just directly clone the source folder from [GitHub](https://github.com/paul-wolf/strgen/tree/master/strgen), the package should still work properly.

Answer (score 11):

Simply add `encoding="utf8"` inside "open('path', here)".

```
with open('path to csv file',  encoding="utf8") as csv_file:
```

Comment: Thank you! I was loading JSON file with the following code:

import json
with open('movie.json', encoding='utf8') as JSONFile:
 data = json.load(JSONFile)
print(len(data['movie'][0]))

and it was throwing the above-mentioned error, by adding "encoding='utf8'" to the "with open()", it is solved.

Answer (score 6):

I also had this problem with a `pip install` on a Windows version of python. The solution is to set the following environment variable:

```
PYTHONUTF8=1
```

You can unset it after the installation is complete if it could interfere with your normal development.

Comment: This is correct if the goal is to obtain Unicode output in UTF-8 encoding, but not a proper solution for the cases where it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/StringGenerator/0.3.0 and download the latest version (or source in this case), extract the .gz file and then the .tar file.

Next go in `StringGenerator-0.2.0` folder and open a terminal and run:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Or from PowerShell run:

```
python ./setup.py build
python ./setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when installing [miservice 2.0.1](https://pypi.org/project/miservice/#files). I have downloaded the package, unpacked tar.gz and emptied Readme.md file (what was causing the error were some Chinese characters in the file). Afterwards I replaced the new empty Readme.md in tar.gz and I installed it with `pip install miservice-2.0.1.tar.gz` with no issues.